# ImportError: cannot import name lzma

Tags: python, pandas, lzma

I have a fairly simple error when I try to do my pandas.csv_read (literally the only command I'm doing), and I don't know how to fix it or where it comes from, never seen it before. Anyone knows?

This is the entire error if it helps :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-81d3d9fb8c5e> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv("LA_TRANSITION_ECOLOGIQUE.csv.xz")

/home/holli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

/home/holli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    427 
    428     # Create the parser.
--> 429     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    430 
    431     if chunksize or iterator:

/home/holli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

/home/holli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1120     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1121         if engine == 'c':
-> 1122             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1123         else:
   1124             if engine == 'python':

/home/holli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1851         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1852 
-> 1853         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1854         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1855 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

/home/holli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.pyc in import_lzma()
    365         """ import the backported lzma library
    366         or raise ImportError if not available """
--> 367         from backports import lzma
    368         return lzma
    369 

ImportError: cannot import name lzma
```

Comment: Can you try renaming the file with ```LA_TRANSITION_ECOLOGIQUEcsv.xz```? or anything that the file only have a single ```.```?

Comment: Yeah I tried changing the name to not have two periods but that still gave me the same error :/